# Why is my yup string array validation schema not working?

Tags: javascript, express, yup

Does anyone have any idea why this isnt working? I have a schema im trying to enforce with yup and ensure that the data inside the array are strings, here is the yup schema:

```js
signUpSchema: async (req, res, next) => {
    const signUpSchema = yup.object().shape({
      username: yup
        .string()
        .required('name is required')
        .typeError('name must be a string'),
      email: yup
        .string()
        .email('email must be a valid email')
        .required('email is required')
        .typeError('email must be a string'),
      password: yup
        .string()
        .required('password is required')
        .typeError('password must be a string'),
      password2: yup
        .string()
        .oneOf([yup.ref('password'), null], 'Passwords must match'),
      isArtist: yup.boolean().required('isArtist is required').typeError('isArtist must be a boolean'),
      areaCode: yup.string().required('areaCode is required').typeError('areaCode must be a string'),

// ! WHY IS THIS NOT WORKING, VALIDATION OF DATA INSIDE ARRAY ISNT WORKING?
      locationTracking: yup
        .array()
        .of(yup.string())
        .required('locationTracking is required')
        .typeError('locationTracking must be an array')
        .min(1, 'locationTracking must have at least one location'),

    });

    try {
      await signUpSchema.validate(req.body);
      next();
    } catch (error) {
      next(error);
    }
  },
```

```js
locationTracking: yup
        .array()
        .of(yup.string())
        .required('locationTracking is required')
        .typeError('locationTracking must be an array')
        .min(1, 'locationTracking must have at least one location'),

    });
```

I also attempted adding the required and typeError methods

```js
locationTracking: yup
            .array()
            .of(yup.string().require().typeError('data must be strings'))
            .required('locationTracking is required')
            .typeError('locationTracking must be an array')
            .min(1, 'locationTracking must have at least one location'),

        });
```

the schema enforces that locationTracking is an array but does not enforce that it needs to be an array of strings. Arrays of numbers, booleans etc all fly by this validation. Not sure what im doing wrong can't find anything online about this issue.

the data being validated is the req.body being sent as json by postman, i thought theres was some sort of type coercion occuring but when i check for the type of data it returns number, boolean etc, so completely flying by my validation

Answer (score 0):

```
let schema = yup.array().of(yup.number().min(2));

await schema.isValid([2, 3]); // => true
await schema.isValid([1, -24]); // => false

schema.cast(['2', '3']); // => [2, 3]
```

[Refer](https://github.com/jquense/yup#array).

Your code

```
locationTracking: yup
            .array()
            .of(yup.string().min(1, 'locationTracking must have at least one location').required())
            .required('locationTracking is required')
        });
```

Comment: Sorry I should have shown the full schema but just thought it would make the post too unnecessarily busy, the locationTracking property is already part of a yup.object() shape.

Comment: I have modified my post. Now try.